# Using the mORMot database replication function fails, just works once after the server are restarted

Tags: database, delphi, database-replication, mormot

Only when the master server is restarted the sync works but only once.

In the slave log I can see the following repeated five times:

```
2023-10-05 09:24:14.640 Debug       mormot.rest.sqlite3.TRestServerDB(035da1e0) RecordVersionSynchronizeSlaveStart(TORMUser) current=19 Subscribe(036ec488)
2023-10-05 09:24:14.640 Enter       mormot.soa.client.TServiceFactoryClient(036fac98).InternalInvoke IServiceRecordVersion.Subscribe("User",19,1) 
2023-10-05 09:24:14.640 Enter          mormot.rest.http.client.TRestHttpClientWebsockets(03d93730).InternalUri POST
2023-10-05 09:24:14.640 Trace             mormot.rest.http.client.TRestHttpClientWebsockets(03d93730) InternalRequest POST calling THttpClientWebSockets(03d939a0).Request
2023-10-05 09:24:14.640 Client            mormot.rest.http.client.TRestHttpClientWebsockets(03d93730) POST DHSSync/ServiceRecordVersion.Subscribe status=200 len=18 state=1
2023-10-05 09:24:14.640 Leave          00.003.082
2023-10-05 09:24:14.640 Service return         mormot.soa.client.TServiceFactoryClient(036fac98) {"result":[false]}
```

and then  I get an error:

```
2023-10-05 09:24:14.704 Error       mormot.rest.sqlite3.TRestServerDB(035da1e0) RecordVersionSynchronizeSlaveStart(TORMUser): retry failure
```

The code in the slave looks like this:

```
procedure TForm5.btnSynchronizeClick(Sender: TObject);
  function setUpSyncServer: TRestServerDB;
  begin
    result := TSQLRestServerDB.Create(CreateSyncModel, ChangeFileExt(Executable.ProgramFileName, '.db'));
    result.DB.Synchronous := smOff;
    result.DB.LockingMode := lmNormal;
    result.Server.CreateMissingTables;
  end;

  begin
    if not fSyncRunning then
    begin
      btnSynchronize.Caption := 'Stopp Synk';
      fSyncServer := SetUpSyncServer;
      fHttpClientSync := TRestHttpClientWebSockets.Create('127.0.0.1', '8888', CreateSyncModel);
      fSyncServer.RecordVersionSynchronizeSlaveStart(TORMUser, fHttpClientSync);
      fSyncRunning := true;
    end
    else
    begin
      btnSynchronize.Caption := 'Synka';
      fSyncServer.RecordVersionSynchronizeSlaveStop(TORMUser);
      freeAndNil(fSyncServer);
      freeAndNil(fHttpClientSync);
     fSyncRunning := false;
   end;
 end;
```

The master part:

```
function setUpOrmSyncServer: TRestServerDB;
begin
  result := TRestServerDB.Create(CreateSyncModel, ChangeFileExt(Executable.ProgramFileName, '.db'));
  result.DB.LockingMode := lmNormal;
end;

begin
  OrmSyncServer := setUpOrmSyncServer;
  HttpSyncServer := TRestHttpServer.Create('8888', [OrmSyncServer], '+', UseBidirSocket,4 );
  OrmSyncServer.RecordVersionSynchronizeMasterStart;
end;
```

So I just wonder, What am I missing?